# Help with graphic card(s)

Tags: linux, nvidia, intel-graphics, graphic-card

I'm a GNU/Linux user and love it, but I have been struggling to correctly install this system on my computer (laptop), all due to the graphic graphics card. Here are the specs of the computer:

```
Intel Core i7-7700HQ (CPU)
Intel HD Graphics 630 (Integrated)
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (Dedicated)
Computer: MSI GL72M 7RDX (just in case you want to know)
```

I've tried several things to make it work and I'll mention them:

First I tried to install Arch and tried to configure xorg (with nouveau and intel and also with nvidia and intel). Whenever I tried to start it, it shuted down.

Then I moved to elementaryOS. In this distro, I couldn't even get to the live USB because it stopped during splash screen. After that, I realized that I had to erase `splash` from kernel parameters and I had to add the `nomodeset` parameter. All went well, until I tried to install `nvidia` proprietary drivers (and blacklist `nouveau`), because it was draining my battery in less than a hour. When I did that, the screen became black and I couldn't even access another tty. I had to install it back (because I tried to uninstall the driver, but nothing happened after that). Then I tried to install `bumblebee` in order to use when to use NVIDIA and when to use Intel. The same happened, but when I uninstalled it, everything was just fine. But then, I removed `wingpanel` to switch to another version of it, but now, the screen is still black, yet I can access another tty. I tried to install it back, but it is still the same.

Before you tag this as duplicate, I have one thing to say. I tried a lot of things used on many situtations similar to mine and NOTHING worked. So, What can I do to have my distro back?

@edit

P.S: Also, when I was on Arch, when I ran `xrandr` or related commands, the output was always like `Cannot find screen`.

P.S 2: System is in dual-boot with Windows, on separate disks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest thing u need to settle on is what linux distribution you want, because the steps to getting nvidia drivers installed & working is not universal.  I am not familiar with arch or elementaryOS.
I am very familiar with SLES {which you won't be using} but OpenSuse you could use and over the last ~2 years I have found Suse to be fairly easy regarding nvidia drivers where it can be as simple as

- download Nvidia...run file, will most likely be x86-64 for you
- switch user or log in as root on your linux system
- init 3 or corresponding systemd or sysctl command to go to run level 3
- execute ./Nvidia..run file
- say yes to automatically modify xorg.conf file

**if the nouveau driver is running by default, that has to be disabled.**
depending on your linux distribution the Nvidia.run file may or may not be able to do that automatically, and depending on your linux distribution sometimes it's as easy as `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and adding *blacklist nouveau*.
Or you may need to add a kernel boot parameter saying don't use nouveau,
Other times you have to do things like *dracut* and create a new *initramfs*

you can read about all that by doing a web search on *linux disable nouveau*

what can also be a big help when no instructions for doing this seem to work for you, is in your boot parameters where you have *splash=silent* set that to *splash=verbose*

Comment: Already did that, forgot to mention. That was my last try, even blacklisting nouveau, but that didn't seem to work. Thanks anyway

Comment: years ago, I had failed getting nvidia working in an earlier version than SLES 11.4; sometimes the graphics in linux can be completely broken/bugged depending on the distribution & version; in my opinion *linux* as a whole is still in the dark ages regarding graphics drivers

Comment: But the problem is: this is the only computer I have this issues. I'm thinking that it is using NVIDIA all the time and it can't access the Intel Graphics card

Comment: maybe try specifying in the bios to explicitly use pci-express graphics card and disable onboard; and make sure you are not running and old bios version; i am not surprised you are having problems since it's a newer laptop if it's not nearly as new a linux distro then linux is probably not recognizing various hardware, chipsets, etc. would be my guess

Comment: and especially efi vs legacy bios and all that; try setting everything to legacy in the bios, don't set anything to "uefi only".

Comment: So, you're saying I should set everything to BIOS? In that case I have to install everything again, or am I wrong?

Comment: possibly, if i had to guess whatever linux you are trying to use does not support your laptop because it is too new.  Look for **OPROM** menu's in the BOIS/UEFI and if they are set to *UEFI ONLY* start setting them all to *legacy* or *bios*.  Keep setting everything to legacy bios if your MSI laptop even supports it; especially if there is a ***Video OPROM Policy***

Comment: anything that is graphics related if it is set to something like *UEFI Only* then set it to *BIOS* or *legacy*.  And look for something called *CSM* **Compatibility Support Module** if you have it and enable it and choose something to the effect of *Legacy/BIOS* anything other than "uefi only"

Comment: Tried to use with CSM, the problem persisted. Reinstalled elementary OS, had to do everything again. Now I have graphical interface working, but had to do all that is mentioned above. I would like to know how to properly configure my system.

Comment: Still have issues!